# Why is nothing being printed in this code?

Tags: python

The aim of the code is to find the largest prime number factor of testNum.

```
testNum = 600851475143

for i in range(2,600851475144):
    global answer
    if testNum % i == 0:
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i % j == 0:
                break
            else:
                answer = i

print(answer)
```

Comment: can you please write your aim and your desired output so that I can suggest you a better way. because you are executing two for loops and loop will execute NxN time where your N will be 600851475144. it is taking too long time to give you answer even if your testNum is single digit number

Comment: If you're using Python 2, range will try to create a list with 600 billion integers. Use xrange or Python 3. Also, brute force isn't the answer for Project Euler. He was a great mathematician and the idea is to think a little before rushing in.

Answer (score 4):

I notice this is [Project Euler Problem 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3).

Your brute force algorithm is far too slow. You're trying to perform 600 billion iterations. You need to come up with a smarter approach to reduce the number of iterations.

This is a common theme in Project Euler problems. The most direct approach rarely works. The problems are designed to require clever algorithms.

Hint: When you find a factor, factor it out.

Comment: Downvoter, what's my error?

Comment: Hint, factors come in pairs, one is always `<= sqrt(product)`.